# Open Office Writer certain documents don't appear in recent documents list

Tags: openoffice, documents

I have a file I copied from another PC, it's password protected and I always have to look it up to open it because it is never saved in recent documents list in Open Office->File.

It is not hidden, and I'm the owner of the file, it has exactly the same security permissions and other properties just like other documents (some of them are also password protected).

It's Win 7 Pro.